# Send an e-mail from XAMPP to an e-mail adress(gmail/yahoo/whatever)

Tags: php, xampp

Hi quys I have a problem with a PHP script. It should send an e-mail to my e-mail adress but it doesn't:(

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<h2> Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2>
<p> Share your story of alien abduction:</p>
<form  method="POST" action="report.php">
<label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
<label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
<label for="email">What is your email adress?</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
<label for="whenithappened">When did it happen?</label>
<input type="text" id="whenithappened" name="whenithappened"><br>
<label for="howlong">How long where you gone?</label>
<input type="text" id="howlong" name="howlong"><br>
<label for="howmany">How many did you see</label>
<input type="text" id="howmany" name="howmany"><br>
<label for="aliendescription">Describe them:</label>
<input type="text" id="aliendescription" name="aliendescription"><br>
<label for="whattheydid">What they do to you?</label>
<input type="text" id="whattheydid" name="whattheydid"><br>
<label for="fangspotted">Have tou see my  dog Fang?</label>
<input type="radio" id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted"  value="YES">Yes
<input type="radio"id="fangspotted" name="fangspotted" value="NO">NO<br>
<img src="img/fang.jpg" alt="Fang Picture" title="Fang Picture"><br>
<label for="other">Anything else you want to add</label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="other" name="other"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send report!">
</body>
</html>
```

That is the HTML part of code, and the PHP script is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Aliens Abducted Me - Report an Abduction</h2>
<?php
$name = $_POST['firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lastname'];
$when_it_happened = $_POST['whenithappened'];
$how_long = $_POST['howlong'];
$how_many = $_POST['howmany'];
$alien_description = $_POST['aliendescription'];
$what_they_did = $_POST['whattheydid'];
$fang_spotted = $_POST['fangspotted'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$other = $_POST['other'];
$to = 'my_email@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Aliens Abducted Me - Abduction Report';
$msg = "$name was abducted $when_it_happened and was gone for $how_long.\n" .
"Number of aliens: $how_many\n" .
"Alien description: $alien_description\n" .
"What they did: $what_they_did\n" .
"Fang spotted: $fang_spotted\n" .
"Other comments: $other";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . $email);
echo 'Thanks for submitting the form.<br/>';
echo 'You were abducted ' . $when_it_happened;
echo ' and were gone for ' . $how_long . '<br />';
echo 'Number of aliens: ' . $how_many . '<br />';
echo 'Describe them: ' . $alien_description . '<br />';
echo 'The aliens did this: ' . $what_they_did . '<br />';
echo 'Was Fang there? ' . $fang_spotted . '<br />';
echo 'Other comments: ' . $other . '<br>';
echo 'Your email address is ' . $email;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My php.ini configurations are :

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = NULL

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = NULL
```

There are no error, not reciving any e-mails on my mail box or spam
Thanks for helping me guys, I want to solve this problem before 21/12 at midnight because I don't like to die with my business unfinised~just kidding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace your SMTP : localhost by a smtp server name valid, for exemple by your web provider or your web hosting stmp. Some of them require to be identifie before sending mai..

Comment: Can U give an example? and how can I find it?

Comment: This link can help you : [link](http://forums.devshed.com/mail-server-help-111/how-to-set-up-php-ini-to-send-mail-from-106329.html)